# Day level Calculation in oracle sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I have two year static data .I have column name as stats_date,P2P_volume .Initially i created following query for single day in oracle sql developer

select '1' as KPI_ID, 'P2P' as KPI_DESC,'22-MAR-17' as dates,
 **(sum(case when STATS_DATE between add_months('22-MAR-17',0)-13
    and add_months('22-MAR-17',0)-7  then P2P_VOLUME else 0 end ))** LAST_WEEK_Volume,

```
  (sum(case when STATS_DATE between add_months('22-MAR-17',0)-6
and add_months('22-MAR-17',0)  then P2P_VOLUME else 0 end )) THIS_WEEK_Volume from table
```

my problem is i want create dynamic query which will give me Last_week_volume,and this_week_volume Date wise for two years.rather than single day

Comment: for refer screenshot please click on--->> "For Example please refer following Screenshoot"

Comment: What have you written so far? Why have you tagged this question `[sql-server]` when you're clearly using Oracle.

Comment: i can easily convert sql-server  query to oracle sql ..so waiting for answer or logic in sql-server.Thanking you!

Comment: It is still not clear what you want.  Please post your test data and also show your expected output  **as text not a screen shot**.

Comment: i already mention in post .I have static data for 2 years .(2015&2016). so i want to do calculation for sum of sales in term of last week,current week day wise... i created static query   which are following ways:             
 select '1' as KPI_ID, 'P2P' as KPI_DESC,'22-MAR-17' as dates,
 (sum(case when STATS_DATE between add_months('22-MAR-17',0)-13
    and add_months('22-MAR-17',0)-7  then sales  else 0 end )) LAST_WEEK_Volume
    FROM fact_product

Comment: So you still haven't clearly explained what you want and you still haven't got an answer. Do you thing these two facts could be related?

Comment: can u tell me what kind of things u didnt understand? so  i will explain accodingly

Comment: Well for a start it's not clear whether the posted screenshot is the input data or the desired output. We need both to suggest a solution.

Comment: screenshot contains desired output. and input contains two years of static data..and main objective is to do calculation on day level for eg.last week revenue,current week revenue

Comment: The fact that you're answering my comments a week after posting the question suggests you still want a solution from us. You're not going to get one until you provide enough information. Please post your table structure and some sample data. Look, you are asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to spend **their time** helping you. The least you can do is **invest some of yours** framing a decent question.

Comment: ok.Input description
In table following column 1. static date,2. p2p_volume (mesure column),
in addition having two year data 

my desire o/p will be date wise calculation of sum  (last_week),sum(current_week)

for example 
static_date sum(last_week) sum(current_week)
01-FEB-17     100               200

i want to do dynamic operation on static data so how to do?

Comment: Still not a complete question but I lack the energy to repeat myself any more. I'm just going to guess the bits you haven't told us.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a complete set of sample data and requirements here are my assumptions:

1. There is one row per day per KPI
2. The definition of `current week`, `previous week` can be satisfied
   by using the `'IW'` date format mask

This solution uses a subquery to calculate the sum of the measures for each week. This feeds into the main query which uses an analytic `lag()` function to show the totals for the current week and the previous week.

```
with cte as (
  select kpi
        , to_char(static_date, 'YYYY') as yr
       , to_char(static_date, 'IW') as wk
       , sum(volume) as wk_volume
       , sum(value) as wk_value
       , sum(revenue) as wk_revenue
  from t23
  group by kpi,to_char(static_date, 'YYYY'), to_char(static_date, 'IW')
)
select kpi
       , yr||'-'||wk as year_wk
       , wk_volume as curr_wk_volume
       , lag(wk_volume) over (order by yr, wk) as prev_wk_volume
       , wk_value as curr_wk_value
       , lag(wk_value) over (order by yr, wk) as prev_wk_value
       , wk_revenue as curr_wk_revenue
       , lag(wk_revenue) over (order by yr, wk) as prev_wk_revenue
from cte
order by 1, 2
/
```

There is [a SQL Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1fb2/3).

Comment: Thanks for reply sir.i got output weekly basis.instead of this i want to do in day level so how can i do it! could you tell me please?

Comment: I am not going to add anything further to this thread until you **edit your question** with a representative set of sample records and an example output which is clearly derived from that data. I have been asking you to do this for a week and you still haven't done so.

Comment: as per ur suggestion i edit my post . and mentioned all things! if still not clear please suggest.

Comment: There really isn't any point is there? I have told you several times what information is required to help you and yet you still have not provided it. Please understand, you are the only person who really cares whether you get the answer you want. I have done my best to help you, but there's a limit and this is it. The ball remains in your court.

Comment: really sorry .what do you mean available data??  i didnt understand. i already mention i have two column stats_date,p2p_volume .on basis of column i need to find out last_week_p2p_volume and current_week_p2p_volume day wise  for 2 years ....so finally my final output should contains daywise last_week_p2p_volume and cureent_week_p2p_volume for 2 years.